# Git: Can we have a folder inside a GIT repository which doesn't care about file HISTORY and just maintain the LATEST contents within that folder

Tags: git

Can we have a folder inside a GIT repository which doesn't care about file HISTORY and just maintain the LATEST contents within that folder.

I tried `gitignore` but it will not serve the purpose, it will simply ignore the contents of the folder.

Comment: The short answer is no: Git just doesn't do that. Keep that folder by some other means.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need those files in your main Git repository, then they will be tracked. Meaning their history (diff) will be recorded.

One workaround would be to:

- isolate that folder as its own GIt repository, where you always to a `git commit --amend` (meaning you overwrite the latest commit by any changes done in that sub-repo)
- add that separate Git repository as submodule.
  But even then, the parent repo would record the submodule main tree SHA1, which would change at each `git commit --amend` done within that submodule folder.